# Project/Variable is not found in .http file - vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, asp.net-web-api, c#-devkit

This is in my .http file:

```
@BuberDinner.Api_HostAddress = http://localhost:5157

GET {{BuberDinner.Api_HostAddress}}/weatherforecast/
Accept: application/json

###
```

I can use the [REST Client](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client) extension to send requests and view the response with no problem. I also have the C# Devkit Extension installed.

In the file, I have the following error showing that I want to get rid of:
[image: BuberDinner is not found]
<sup>*Error: BuberDinner is not found*</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it's just a variable declared in the .http file, and by default it uses the name of the project. And it looks like it complains if variable name has dots. So, I changed the name to not include any dots.